# ML9 setup cluster

Tags: marklogic-9

I setup cluster on three servers for fail over hosts.  is that correct setup cluster? Thanks.

1) Master server1 install ML9, After the server restarts, it will be prompted to join a cluster,skip.

2) install ML9 on slave server 2, After the server restarts, it will be prompted to join a cluster. I enter slave server3 IP address.

3)install ML9 on slave server 3, After the server restarts, it will be prompted to join a cluster.  I will enter Master server1 IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second step seems off. You need to point to a host that already participates in the cluster, so you need to point to server 1 in step 2, and you can point to server 1 or 2 in step 3.

Once hosts have joined the same cluster, you can start setting up, and spreading data load with local forest replication.

HTH!